# R Plotly how to remove the grouping on the added linear regression line

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to draw a plot where, for the scatter plot, the color represents the region. However I noticed when I added a linear regression line, it still follows the color coding (and grouping on) on regions therefore it makes the line so odd and the legend is too messy.

I'm wondering whether there is a way to add a fitted line but ignore the region, or is there a way to still keep the legend for circles but remove the ones for lines? Thanks

[image]

My code for plotly looks like the following:

```
fig1 <- plot_ly(data = df1, 
            x = ~GDP_per_Capita, 
            y = ~Top_1000_Uni_per_Pop,
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "markers",
            color = ~Region,
            size = ~Top_1000_Uni,

            hoverinfo = "text",
            text = paste("Country: ", df1$TableName, 
                 "<br>", 
                 "Region: ", df1$Region)
            ) %>%

        add_lines(data=df1, x = ~GDP_per_Capita, y = fitted(lr1), 
                  line = list(width = 0.5, dash = "dot", color="red")) %>%

        layout(showlegend = TRUE,
               legend = list(orientation = 'l'),
               title="Top Universities vs GDP per Capita",
               xaxis=list(title="GDP per Capita", showgrid = T),
               yaxis=list(title="Top 1000 University per million Population", showgrid = T))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AmadeusNing you are basically there. Plotly lets you "configure" every trace and the legend that comes with it (including having it combined with other traces).
You can easily fix this with the showlegend parameter in the trace call. To remove the legend: showlegend = FALSE.

I do not have your data, so I revert back to the classical mpg dataset and define a simple linear regression for the line. I also stress the line width for presentation purposes in my example graph.

```
    # define a regression line
    lr <- lm(hwy ~ displ, mpg)

    # draw basis plotly plot, create grouping by setting cyl as factor
    fig1 <- plot_ly(data = mpg, x = ~displ, y = ~hwy, color = ~as.factor(cyl)
                    , type = "scatter", mode = "markers")

    # add regression line
    fig1 <- fig1 %>% 
       add_lines(data=mpg %>% group_by(cyl), x = ~displ, y = fitted(lr)
                 , line = list(width = 2, dash = "dot", color="red")
           #----------------- remove legend for line - comment out to see it displayed
                 , showlegend = FALSE
     )
```

[image: remove legend by setting showlegend = FALSE]

Comment: Thanks @Ray. I was tring to turn off the legend but I failed to added it within add_lines....